# How to create a fake light of this type when the normals that are directed to the light object?

Tags: shaders, normals

I'm looking for roughly the same result.

( in the example I'm spinning the big sphere along with the small sphere ( which represents the fake light ) around the big sphere's origin. )

[image]

I think the algorithm below might work, but I don't understand how to implement it in Shader Graph.

The point is to take the `Light source pos` vector in the Vertex space of each vertex of the mesh and normalize it. Then calculate Dot product.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using two texture corrdinates and using the object coordinates of the light for one of them. Then simply Vector Math: Dot Product.

[image]
[image]

Note: There is a  small problem with this setup which I haven't been able to identify the solution to. The gradient isn't perfect. It reaches 1 too early. So like if you use a color ramp after this. it probably won't work.

Comment: Here you can see that the approach and distance of the "light source" changes the gradient. It is necessary that the gradient does not change.

https://media.giphy.com/media/v1.Y2lkPTc5MGI3NjExNGFxMHJseW1nYTBheWRxMXRkeHdzN3h1d3V5M2N3ZGlxM2UwMjF5MCZlcD12MV9pbnRlcm5hbF9naWZfYnlfaWQmY3Q9Zw/mRBKPZjYvSLLQ0YPZF/giphy.gif

Here I showed one of the options that should work, but I don't know how to implement it. Might be worth thinking along those lines.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRSby.png

Comment: There is also an option to take the texture coordinates of the object, isolate one of the axes through XYZ Separate and simply twist the texture coordinates of the objects somehow so that the isolated axis always looks towards the "Light source", turning in its direction when it is moved.